# How does the length of string around a rod affect the friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, string

I'm trying to figure out the following. How and why does the force of friction increase when I wrap a string more times around a rod? I know that the frictional force is related to the normal force. Does wrapping the string around the rod several times increase the normal force? Is it related to surface area? I might need to request a free-body diagram to help understand.

Comment: the available friction will certainly increase given that the total area of surface contact increases with each wrapping loop of the string on the rod. Perhaps you meant to ask if the applied torque on the rod increases as the number of wrapping loops of the string increases, assuming that the tension differential between the beginning and end of the string remains constant.

Comment: Background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation

Answer (score 1):

If a rod of a given legth is wrapped once with a rope and then you wrap one more time then the initial rope on the rod gets pushed inwards more because of the normal force from the new upper layer of the rope.

The new upper layer pushes the layer of the rope under it and hence the normal force between the rod and the layer in  contact gets increased and hence the friction force gets increased.

Hope it helps .

Comment: @QwertyYou was that helpful ?